# Passing invalid value to data variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sorry for my bad english,
Hi, I'm beginer in Vue and I have iussue, which can't to solve.
I load data about art from API (just a list of dicts), and then I making multi array (list of lists), when I save raw response.data, and my multi array in data variable of vue instanse I'm getting the similar data, but i don't change sourse list:

[image: info - multi_array]
[image: raw - raw response.data object]

In raw variable fields offsetX and offsetY must must not exist. And field height is broken too.
That fields also passing in raw variable, and I don't know why.
Code of my app:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            raw: null,
            info: null,
            art_width: 252,
            window_width: null,
            window_height: null,
        },
        mounted() {
            this.window_width = window.innerWidth
            this.window_height = window.innerHeight 
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/content/art',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                app.raw = response.data.items.slice();
                // If i delete create_array from app, raw variable is normal
                app.info = create_array(app.raw)
            });
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                if (app.raw !== null){
                    app.info = create_array(app.raw)
                    this.window_width = window.innerWidth
                    this.window_height = window.innerHeight 
                }
            });
        },
        computed: {
            arts_in_line () {
                return parseInt((this.window_width - 24*2) / (this.art_width+10));
            },
            center_div_width ()  {
                return this.arts_in_line * (this.art_width + 10)
            }
        }
    })

});


function create_array(info) {
    // Gets number of arts in line
    arts_in_line = parseInt((window.innerWidth - 24*2) / (252+10));
    // For return 
    var multi_array = [];
    // Create mulri array
    for (var index = 0; index < info.length; index = index + arts_in_line) {
        multi_array.push(info.slice(index, index+arts_in_line));
    }
    // Save vertical offsets
    var top_offset = []
    for (var row = 0; row < multi_array.length; row ++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < multi_array[row].length; col ++) {
            // scale of art
            let scale = 252 / multi_array[row][col]['width'];
            // Calculation new height and offsetX/Y values
            if (row == 0) {
                top_offset[col] = parseInt(multi_array[row][col]['height'] * scale) + 10;
                multi_array[row][col]['offsetY'] = 0;
                multi_array[row][col]['offsetX'] = (252+10) * col + 'px';
                multi_array[row][col]['height'] = multi_array[row][col]['height'] * scale + 'px';
                multi_array[row][col]['width'] = 252 + 'px';
            } 
            else {
                multi_array[row][col]['offsetY'] = top_offset[col] + 'px';
                top_offset[col] = top_offset[col] + parseInt(multi_array[row][col]['height'] * scale) + 10;
                multi_array[row][col]['offsetX'] = (252+10) * col + 'px';
                multi_array[row][col]['height'] = multi_array[row][col]['height'] * scale + 'px';
                multi_array[row][col]['width'] = 252 + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
    return multi_array;
}
```

Comment: When you are calculating the height  `multi_array[row][col]['height']` you are not parsing the original height. so what your code is doing for example is `(10px * scale) + px` when it should be `(10 * scale) + px`. To fix this you just need to do what you have done before `parseInt(multi_array[row][col]['height']) * scale`

Comment: I've also noticed that you might need to do the same for your scale calulation `let scale = 252 / parseInt(multi_array[row][col]['width'])`. That might fix your issues

Comment: Tnx, you helped me. But after I maked changes, all is working, but still offsetX and offsetY also are added in raw variable, but I don't push its in there. I don't want collect offset params in raw variable.

Comment: I'll write as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
// Create mulri array
    for (var index = 0; index < info.length; index = index + arts_in_line) {
        multi_array.push(info.slice(index, index+arts_in_line));
    }
```

you can simply just create a new array `multi_array` and loop through `info` adding what you want to `multi_array`.
For example

```
    var multi_array = [];
    // Save vertical offsets
    var top_offset = []
    for (var row = 0; row < info.length; row ++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < info[row].length; col ++) {
             let scale = 252 / parseInt(info[row][col]['width']);

             const temp = {
                id: info[row][col]['id'],
                // Additional values you want
                height: (parseInt(multi_array[row][col]['height']) * scale) + 'px'
             }

             multi_array[row][col] = temp
        }
    }

    return multi_array;
```

This way you can add and exclude any key you want in your new array.

Comment: Info array have only 1 row, therefore I create multi_array, and that needs me for create one more array - top_offset, for collecting sum of offsets for each row in col before current row. I don't have any trouble with code working, but i can't understand why create_array function pass 'offsetX' and 'offsetY' into row variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have `multi_array[row][col]['offsetY'] = 0;` and
`multi_array[row][col]['offsetX'] = (252+10) * col + 'px';` being added in your code, you can just remove that. If you are still having issues then after the `if else` you can use `delete multi_array[row][col].offsetX` and `delete multi_array[row][col].offsetY`

Comment: I want to collect two different arrays, 1 - raw response.data from api ,which collect all arts in 1 line, second - multi_array (info) for displaying arts on page, offsets needs for this, i want store they only in info variable not in raw, of course it's not important, because all work with this trouble, but i wanna know why it happen.

Comment: The objects in app.raw and app.info are referencing one another, they still have an observer attached to them so when you change one it changes the other. See [here](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern). You will need to copy the object like this `var newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject)`, this will remove the observer

Comment: For tests I added var newObject = Object.assign({}, response.data.items) after app.raw = response.data.items.slice(); and this also containt offset params, why... create_array called after... what's wrong...

Comment: You will have to write that within your `for (var index = 0; index < info.length; index = index + arts_in_line) {` loop. You will need to loop through each object in your info.slice, use the object assign into a new array which you then push onto the multi_array in the loop

Comment: Tnx for helping me, but I already trying this too, and it doesn't work, but thanks, I just forgot about this bug.

Comment: No problem, I hope I helped in some way